# How to show last ID when All ID on DIV click

Tags: javascript, html

I am newbie with javascript.
i want to make mini game quiz. But stuck on this logic.

Try see my code below,,,
I want to replace div ID "wrong-gameOne" with div ID "correct-gameOne"
after click all div ID wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, wrong4,

I have try make it, but after click one ID "wrong 1" or other, div ID "correct-gameOne" is show. I don't want like this.
Please give me fix my script below how to make it.
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks so much :blush:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 0,
      top: 100,
    }, 500);

    var divs = ['#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4'];

    if ($(this).next(divs).length === 1)
      $('#wrong-gameOne').eq(0).hide();
    else
      $('#correct-gameOne').eq(0).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<img id="correct-gameOne" class="rightAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/10/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" style="display:none;" />
<img id="wrong-gameOne" class="wrongAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/125/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" />

<div id="wrong1" class="no-bottom">
  <label>TEXT 1</label>
</div>

<div id="wrong2" class="no-bottom">
  <label>TEXT 2</label>
</div>

<div id="wrong3" class="no-bottom">
  <label>TEXT 3</label>
</div>

<div id="wrong4" class="no-bottom">
  <label>TEXT 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hallo :), I want to change little code, yesterday i was replace div ID "wrong-gameOne" with div ID "correct-gameOne" after click all div ID wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, wrong4, Now, i want if after click all div ID wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, wrong4 then wrong 4 is clickable for show id="correct-gameOne" then go direct url ... Thank youuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
 $(function () {
    var divs = ["wrong1", "wrong2", "wrong3", "wrong4"];
    $('#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0,
           top: 100,
         }, 500);
    divs.splice(divs.indexOf($(this).prop("id")),1)
    if(divs.length == 0){
        $('#wrong-gameOne').eq(0).hide();
       $('#correct-gameOne').eq(0).show();
    }                
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14qgzdom/1/)