# How to Direct url When All ID on DIV click

Tags: javascript, html

I want make mini game but stuck with logic code.

Try see my code below,,,
I want to direct after click all div ID wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, then wrong4 (the last) its value for direct. Something add class maybe.

I want before the last click ID wrong4, The ID wrong4 its addclass rightAnswers. Because class rightAnswers have attribute html5 data-current-game="5" data-next-game="finish" for next result page.

I have try make it and helping by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar
Helping by Tushar, [How to show last ID when All ID on DIV click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541422/how-to-show-last-id-when-all-id-on-div-click),

But now i want different logic.

Thank you

**Note :** 
I have try edit like this,
But the class rightAnswers not function ...

```
    divs.splice(divs.indexOf($(this).prop("id")), 1)
    if (divs.length == 0) {
      $('#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4').addClass('rightAnswers');
    }
```

And add script url direction like this :
But the class rightAnswers still not function

```
$(".rightAnswers").click(function() {
  window.location = "/game/result";
});
```

Code From [How to show last ID when All ID on DIV click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541422/how-to-show-last-id-when-all-id-on-div-click)

```js
 $(function () {
   var divs = ["wrong1", "wrong2", "wrong3", "wrong4"];
   $('#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4').click(function () {
      $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: 100,
            }, 500);
    divs.splice(divs.indexOf($(this).prop("id")),1)
    if(divs.length == 0){
      $('#wrong-gameOne').eq(0).hide();
     $('#correct-gameOne').eq(0).show();
    }
                    
  });
});
```

```html
 <img id="correct-gameOne" class="rightAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/10/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" style="display:none;" />
    <img id="wrong-gameOne" class="wrongAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/125/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" />
    <div id="wrong1" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 1</label>
    </div>

    <div id="wrong2" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 2</label>
    </div>

    <div id="wrong3" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 3</label>
    </div>

    <div id="wrong4" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 4</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by direct?

Comment: Please provide more information about what u really want to achieve, if u just want to redirect to another page use this `window.location="yourNextPageUrl";`

Comment: sorry if my question is confused. I want before the last click ID wrong4, The ID wrong4 its addclass rightAnswers. Because class rightAnswers have attribute html5 data-current-game="5" data-next-game="finish" for next result page.