# How to get value when All ID click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make mini game but stuck with logic code.

Try see my code below,,,
I want to direct after click all div ID wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, then wrong4 (the last) its value for direct. Something add class maybe.

I want before the last click ID wrong4, The ID wrong4 its addclass rightAnswers. Because class rightAnswers have attribute html5 data-current-game="5" data-next-game="finish" for next result page.

I have try make it and helping by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar
Helping by Tushar, [How to show last ID when All ID on DIV click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541422/how-to-show-last-id-when-all-id-on-div-click),

But now i want different logic.

Thank you

**Note :** 
I have try edit like this,
But the class rightAnswers not function ...

```
    divs.splice(divs.indexOf($(this).prop("id")), 1)
    if (divs.length == 0) {
      $('#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4').addClass('rightAnswers');
    }
```

And add script url direction like this :
But the class rightAnswers still not function, 
**I want class rightAnswers is working if i click.**

```
$(".rightAnswers").click(function() {
  window.location = "/game/result";
});
```

Code From [How to show last ID when All ID on DIV click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541422/how-to-show-last-id-when-all-id-on-div-click)

```js
 $(function () {
   var divs = ["wrong1", "wrong2", "wrong3", "wrong4"];
   $('#wrong1, #wrong2, #wrong3, #wrong4').click(function () {
      $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: 100,
            }, 500);
    divs.splice(divs.indexOf($(this).prop("id")),1)
    if(divs.length == 0){
      $('#wrong-gameOne').eq(0).hide();
     $('#correct-gameOne').eq(0).show();
    }
                    
  });
});
```

```html
 <img id="correct-gameOne" class="rightAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/10/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" style="display:none;" />
    <img id="wrong-gameOne" class="wrongAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/125/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" />
    <div id="wrong1" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 1</label>
    </div>

    <div id="wrong2" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 2</label>
    </div>

    <div id="wrong3" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 3</label>
    </div>

    <div id="wrong4" class="no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 4</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: yeah i also have no clue what your trying to do, doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: as you see from https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/2s0wuL0a/ that is correct, But i want when click last ID wrong4 (this ID go to url). As sample i give wrong4 a new class 'rightAnswers' but not working. I want class rightAnswers is working if i click.

Comment: In plain English: Are you wanting something to happen when something is wrong and something to happen when right. Forget your wrong1-4... for a minute, In plain English explain visually what you are wanting to happen. I.E. I see 4 links and 1 picture. I assume there is a condition, like if the correct one is clicked then do xyz. How is the the correct one determined, and what should it do when correct or not.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle for you.... hopefully this helps you understands , this is not the answer just trying help you clear up the noise, https://jsfiddle.net/Lwpgst5z/8/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're doing, but I think this fixes your code.  Here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/2s0wuL0a/

html:

```
<div id="game1"> 
    <img class="rightAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/10/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" style="display:none;" />
    <img class="wrongAnswer" src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/125/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" />
    <div id='1' class="wrong no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 1</label>
    </div>
    <div id='2' class="wrong no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 2</label>
    </div>
    <div id='3' class="wrong no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 3</label>
    </div>
    <div id='4' class="wrong no-bottom">
        <label>TEXT 4</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
 $(function () {
   var divs = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
   $('#game1 .wrong').click(function () {
      $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: 100,
            }, 500);
    divs.splice(divs.indexOf($(this).prop("id")),1)
    console.log(divs);
    console.log(divs.length);
    if(divs.length == 0){
        $('#game1 .wrongAnswer').hide();
        $('#game1 .rightAnswer').show();
    }

  });
});
```

---

Here's a revised version.  And a new jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/1ocnoaaa/2/

html:

```
<div id="game1">
    <img src="https://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/10/thumbnail.jpg" data-current-game="1" data-next-game="2" />
    <div id="target1"></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
 $(function () {
     function createGame(num) {
         var answers = [{
             text: "TEXT 1"
         }, {
             text: "TEXT 2"
         }, {
             text: "TEXT 3"
         }, {
             text: "TEXT 4"
         }];
         var target = $("#target" + num);
         answers.forEach(function (answer, k) {
             var aid = 'a' + num + '-' + k;
             $("<div />")
                 .addClass("answer no-bottom")
                 .attr('id', aid)
                 .html(answer.text)
                 .appendTo(target);
             answer.id = aid;
         });

         $('#game1 .answer').click(function () {
             var $this = $(this);
             $this.addClass('wrongAnswer');
             var hasMoreAnswers,
                 thisAnswer = _.find(answers, function(answer) {
                     return answer.id === $this.attr('id');
                 });
             thisAnswer.tried = true;
             hasMoreAnswers = _.find(answers, function(answer) {
                 return answer.tried !== true;
             });
             if (!hasMoreAnswers) {
                 window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
             }
         });
     }
     createGame(1);
 });
```

style:

```
.wrongAnswer {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: Sorry before, i mean, why jquery addclass not function if click ? but css is working. i want if click class rightAnswers its working go to url